# How to balance the satuations of the colour used in my design?

Tags: color, color-theory, design-principles, resume

[image: CV design]

Hi there, we've been designing this to present our profiles for a while now. We just felt something might be off with the colour. Please let me know if you got any thoughts on any points to improve

The key point we are unsure of:
Is it overloaded with different situations of blue? Would it be tiring for the eyes when you first looked at it?

We'll be extremely grateful for any feedback as we definitely need a fresh perspective.

Many thanks!

Comment: Just pure *opinion*... the gradients break it. Especially that large color transition for the background. Simply removing the gradients, or making them *far, far* more subtle would go a long way to making the page "feel" more high-end and intentional. I'm also not a fan of a box within a box within a box within a box. Visual separation is clear enough that you could probably remove the larger box indicator on the left.

Comment: Colour choice is highly subjective, so all you will get here is opinions.  I would agree with Scott however - there are too many gradients.  Also in general I feel the design is too cluttered - do you really need all those boxes?

Comment: Thank you Scott, great advice! We never thought about the background, so really great perspective! 
Also we definitely don't need those many boxes, thank you both!